# Power Bi: Calculating variation between diffrent production for the same Item

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a production report for my company on Power bi. My model has the following table:

- ProductionTable: ProdID, ItemID, quantity, prodDate. The ProdID column is unique and the ItemID column is repeatable (Meaning the same Item can have different ProdID)

-ProductionDetailTable: ProdID, TypeofCost (raw material, direct labor and OH),Costs

-DateTable

There is one to many relationship between my productionTable and the ProductionDetailTable

My aim is to calculate the the variation (in regards to the type of Costs) between latest production and the previous one, to analyse the production efficency. I have a matrix visual where I display the following:

| Cost_Type | ProdID1 | ProdID2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RM | 2 | 8 |  |
| DL | 5 | 9 |  |
| OH | 6 | 10 |  |

I have have also a slicer where I select the different products.

Now I am stuck at the step where I have to compare each prodcution with the previous one.

I tried ranking each prodID by prodDate for each Item. My idea is the to use the ranking as a basis to retrive the previous production,but I was not successfull in doing that.

Comment: How do you determine "Previous"? Previous Day?

Comment: the Previous Production is determined by the production date (in the productionTable)